# Oracle select query is invalid number in C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have a code that I use to login.
I call the data I get from textbox with a method and check the records with select query in the
database.

I call to relevant method , when I press the button.

```
 private void btnGiris_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginBilgiler lb = new LoginBilgiler();
            bool sonuc = lb.GirisKontrol(txtAd.Text, txtSifre.Text);
        }
```

But I encounter errors in cmd.ExecuteReader  the below.

```
    public bool GirisKontrol(string ad,string sifre)
    {
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {


            string query = String.Format("SELECT count(*) from Z_LABEL_USER where USERNAME=({0}) and PASSWORD=({1})", ad,sifre);
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                kAdi = ad;
                con.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
                con.Close();
                return false;
        }
    }
```

The table I use for the select query.

[image]

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-01722: invalid
> number'

Comment: *Don't* construct SQL strings like that. That's how SQL injection attacks occur. In this case though, you probably ended up with the raw text inside the query. ADO.NET allows you to use parameterised queries instead of string concatenation.

Comment: `String.Format("SELECT count(*) from Z_LABEL_USER where USERNAME='{0}' and PASSWORD='{1}'", ad,sifre)`

Comment: You should never store cleartext passwords nor test for validity like this either. Someone could *easily* pass eg `'moo') OR 1=1 //`  as the username or password and log in, even though `COUNT(*)` returned all records. There's no need to write your own password storage code though. .NET, going all the way to .NET 1.0, offers secure password storage first through the Membership providers, now through Identity and Identity Server

Comment: Do you store passwords as clear text in your database???

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya that's even worse. Now it's even easier to attack this code

Comment: No , I encrypt and store passwords

Comment: Yes... It is open to SQL injection... I am just trying to fix the current error for the OP.... Definitely using parameterized query is better approach. Thank you for pointing that out... @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I guess Parameterised queries safer than that

Comment: As for password storage in general, they aren't stored AT ALL. They should be salted and hashed at least 1000 times with a strong cryptographic hashing algorithm. Check Troy Hunt's [Stronger password hashing in .NET with Microsoft’s universal providers](https://www.troyhunt.com/stronger-password-hashing-in-net-with/) and probably all of his blog posts

Comment: The code does not even opens to SQL injection - it is a flaw itself because `COUNT(*)` always returns a row, so `dr.HasRows` is **always** true, no matter if you provide wrong password or not!

Comment: @Hakanözel encrypting is no better. The password is still there. That's why it's standard guidance to hash password for over a decade now. Someone is always going to store one of the common leaked passwords in your database. With GPUs one could simply try multiple master password combinations until they found a decrypted password that matches one of the common passwords.

Comment: Troy Hunt's article was written in 2012. Password encryption was frowned upon for at least 7 years before that. I don't think the ASP.NET provider in 2010 allowed password encryption and recovery anymore, and even if it did, it was understood to be insecure and *only* available for compatibility reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, don't hardcode parameters in SQL; parametrize it instead:

```
public bool GirisKontrol(string ad, string sifre) {
  //DONE: validate public methods' input
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ad))
    return false; // or throw exception
  else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sifre))
    return false; // or throw exception

  using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString)) {
    con.Open();

    //DONE: no need to count all the entires, just check if there's at least one 
    //DONE: keep query readable
    //DONE: paramterize queries   
    string query = 
      @"select 1 
          from Z_LABEL_USER 
         where USERNAME = :prm_UserName 
           and PASSWORD = :prm_Password";
    
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con)) {
      //TODO: this syntax can vary from library to library you use to work with Oracle
      cmd.Parameters.Add(":prm_UserName", OracleType.VarChar).Value = ad;
      cmd.Parameters.Add(":prm_Password", OracleType.VarChar).Value = sifre;

      using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        if (dr.Read()) {
          //TODO: Side effect : it changes instance's state. Do you really want it?
          kAdi = ad;

          return true;
        }  
      }
    } 
  }
 
  return false;
}
```